# Exercise 3, Section 6.7 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, direct-product, linear-independence

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Let $R$ be the range of $T$ and let $N$ be the null space of $T$. Prove that $R$ and $N$ are independent if and only if $V=R\oplus N$.

**My attempt:** $(\Rightarrow )$ Suppose $R$ and $N$ are independent. We need to show $V=R+N$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3624873/861687) is a proof using dimension. Can we prove $V=R+N$ directly from definition? I mean, let $\alpha \in V$. Show $\exists \alpha_1\in R$, $\exists \alpha_2\in N$ such that $\alpha =\alpha_1 + \alpha_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$R$ and $N$ are independent"? is it $R\cap N=\{0\}$? I don't think this expression is standard.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes. $R$ and $N$ are independent$\iff$$R\cap N=\{0\}$.

Comment: Why do you want to prove it "directly" rather that using dimension, and what were your attempts to do so? It holds only if $\dim V<\infty$ and you can always  "hide" a proof of the rank-nullity theorem inside a proof of this exercise and pretend to have found a "direct" proof, but what for?

Comment: @AnneBauval I also think it is very hard write $\alpha =\alpha_1 +\alpha_2$. We don’t have any “nice” structure on $T$, for instance $T^2=T$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval btw [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4554583/861687) is another example of showing two subspace are equal using dimension. Without dimension argument it is quiet hard to prove equality.